# How can i open this html body form in a webview?

Tags: java, android, html, webview

> \r\n
>   https://my.click.uz/pay/\" method=\"post\"
>   id=\"click_form\">\r\n                            \r\n
>   \r\n
>   \r\n                            \r\n
>   \r\n                            \r\n
>   \r\n                            \r\n
>   \r\n                    "

Answer (score 0):

You can load this at a `TextView` using `Html.fromHtml()` like below:

```
String source = "your source";
txt.setText(Html.fromHtml(source, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
```